# How to cover the exterior gap around window to hide foam caulk

Tags: windows

I just replaced a window. I have an ugly gap between the window and the brick. I've filled it with foam caulk as insulation, but now I need to cover it up so it looks good.

[image: DIY window installation]

We had other windows professionally installed. The professionals covered the gap with some plastic thing—not sure what it is called. If I knew what it was called, I could search for it to buy it for the window I installed.

[image: Professional window installation]

**How to cover up the gap?**

(Sorry for the poor pictures.)

Comment: window trim/molding - they probably used material made of pvc instead of wood, so it wouldn't rot, but is still easily cut, fastened and painted just like wood.

Comment: When I search for window trim/molding at the big box retailers, I find the trim for inside of the house.

Comment: You could just use PVC molding, of which a variety are available at your local big box, and glue it to the window and brick.  No need to paint, won't rot.  Might need to trim some of the excess foam for a flat/square surface.

Comment: There's lots of "interior" trim, too; I think the main issue for exterior use is whether it holds up to UV light exposure without painting. Anyway, just search for "exterior pvc window trim"

Comment: PVC exterior molding is exactly what I need. I've since discovered that the term is "flat trim".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thin plastic strips can be purchased from most diy outlets. Otherwise, find a local pvc window manufacturer, who will undoubtedly stock strips which their own fitters will use for situations such as this.

Answer (score 0):

##### What about water?

You should have had some flashing there to catch water behind the brick or dripping down the brick and direct it in front of the window, so it won't crawl in.   The foam should be behind the flashing.  If you want to be meticulous, watch [these videos](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/project-guides/windows-doors/how-to-install-a-pvc-exterior-casing-on-a-window-in-a-brick-wall) especially the last couple about flashing and finishing.

If you don't want to go back and do all that, I think you should

1. cut the foam back into the gap to make room for caulk
2. Fill the gap, in front of the foam, with caulk
3. Glue an L-shaped PVC drip strip to the underside of the brick opening, not to the window, to catch water dripping down the wall and keep it away from your gap.

That's not "the way" to flash a window but it's better than having water attacking your foam-filled gap.